# How to edit a photo inside a question post?

Tags: support, edits, images

I have recently asked a question on Stack Exchange which contains an image, and the image contains a piece of text with a typo.

I wanted to know if I can change that photo and how to do it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no way to edit an image uploaded from the editor Stack Exchange uses. You have to upload a new one, or download the original and edit that, then upload it again.

The steps to edit an image in your post are:

- Click on the edit button under your post.
- Remove the `[![enter image description here][1]][1]` and `[1]: ...` part.
- Click on the Insert Image button to add a new image.

Answer (score 7):

Stack Exchange doesn't have an built-in picture editor. The best you can do is download the image, edit it in GIMP, Paint, Photoshop, edit the post and re-upload it.

If you were not the author of the post, you could leave a comment pointing out the typo. The author might be able to recreate the image without the typo.

Answer (score 4):

> I wanted to know if I can change that photo and How to do it.

There are no built-in image editing tools on the site.

You would need to download the image, alter it and upload the altered image, replacing the original.